# Creating a simple form

Tags: weblogic, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am looking for some tutorials on creating a simple form using Oracle ADF and JDeveloper. I am not able to find any relevant materials on the internet.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried http://oracle.com/JDev ?
for example:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18941_01/tutorials/jdtut_11r2_55/jdtut_11r2_55_1.html